# Black Hole Matter to Subatomic Exchange

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, energy-conservation, event-horizon, hawking-radiation

When matter enters a black hole with a singularity the particles smaller than photons like (fermions and bosons) released come from within the black hole or do subatomic particles shed from matter just before matter passes the horizon?

Comment: Hi Jen. Are you asking where Hawking radiation comes from?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/22498/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lets take this one at a time:

> When matter enters a black hole with a singularity

What is matter? Ultimately matter is a bound complex of [elementary particles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_particle) and [energy](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/enecon.html).

There exist free, not in a composite structure, elementary particles with energy too, the electrons and the neutrinos and the photons.

The photons in aggregate build up the electromagnetic waves , of which visible light is a part of the spectrum.

> the particles smaller than photons

As far as our scientific modeling of the observations has taken us, **there are no smaller particles than the elementary particles, photon included.** The elementary particles are point particles. Matter generally passes the horizon whole , in its complexity.

> *the particles* released come from within the black hole

(italics mine

Hawking radiation comes from the [event horizon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole#Event_horizon), not beyond.

> or do subatomic particles shed from matter just before matter passes the horizon?

**No** shedding of subatomic particles, because they are bound to the particle with much stronger forces than gravity. A proton falls whole. The particles in the elementary particle table too. A molecule might shed some electrons if it hits another molecule with enough energy, and in general such interactions can happen but the momentum given by the black hole attraction will eat up most fragments except the ones that will give the [black body radiation of the black hole](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/137445/hawking-blackbody-radiation-emission-or-absorption) which is the Hawking radiation.